# Sending EMail with Javamail via Exchange Server

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

we have an Exchange Server and i wanted to test sending a mail with it. But somehow i always get the error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1889)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at Test.sendMailJava(Test.java:89)
at Test.main(Test.java:29)
```

i tried looking at our exchange if anonymous users were allowed and they are, our Printer also send Mails without any authentification.

Here is my Java code, hope someone can help:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.simplejavamail.email.Email;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.Mailer;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.config.ProxyConfig;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.config.ServerConfig;
import org.simplejavamail.util.ConfigLoader;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
////        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sendMailJava();
}

public static void sendMailJava()
{
    String to = "Recipient"
    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "Sender";

    // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
    String host = "Server Ip-Adress";

    // Get system properties
    Properties  properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable","true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Subject");
        // Now set the actual message
        message.setContent("Content", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    }catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I also tried SimpleMail, but there is the same error.

The Connection to the smtp Server seems to work, but the message cannot be send, cause of the error above. What could it be?

Greetings,

Kevin

Edit:

i found my error, i don't know why our printers can send maisl without errors but it seems i had to whitelist my ip at our exchange server. Code was completely fine.

thanks for the help

Comment: Why don't you have them create an account on the exchange server for you and use EWS to send mail?

Comment: i have an account on the server, but i wanted to try sending an email without using outlook, like i said our scanners and printers also send mails without any authentification and that is ok, so it must work somehow... i have the theory that something in the header or text of the mail is not ok, so that the spamfilter immediatly catches the email, but i don't know what

Comment: I know here in our office, the smtp port isn't even open on our server. If I were a network admin and that was open, I would setup the server so that only specific IP's could use that and the rest would be considered spam.

Comment: why shouldn't the smtp port be open? i mean our company wants to send mails right? and i am an system administrator at our company, i don't see any restriction from our server

Comment: Because Exchange doesn't use smtp. It uses mapi

Comment: ok then is there any way to change my method into using mapi?

Comment: Without third party libraries, I do not know how. This was why I originally suggested using EWS. This will use mapi and requires you to sign into the exchange server.

Comment: there has to be another way, when i'm finished programming, i want this to work on all systems, they just have to have an available server  Edit: i just checked the exchange server and we are definitely using smtp and not mapi

Comment: Considering there are three email protocols, to have it work on all systems you will need to implement all three email protocols (smtp, mapi, and imap). Take a look at EWS Api for Java. It is written by Microsoft (though it is somewhat old).

Comment: i just want this code above to work, it has to, maybe someone else had a similar problem and solved it

Answer (score 1):

I know you are wanting the smtp option, but I have a feeling the issue is how your server is setup and not in your code. If you get the EWS-Java Api, you can log into your exchange server directly and grab mail that way. Below is the code that would make that work:

```
 public class ExchangeConnection {
      private final ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2); // change to whatever server you are running, though 2010_SP2 is the most recent version the Api supports

      public ExchangeConnection(String username, String password) {
           try {
                service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(username, password));
                service.setUrl(new URI("https://(your webmail address)/ews/exchange.asmx"));
           }
           catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }

      public boolean sendEmail(String subject, String message, List<String> recipients, List<String> filesNames) {
           try {
                EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
                email.setSubject(subject);
                email.setBody(new MessageBody(message));
                for (String fileName : fileNames) email.getAttachments().addFileAttachment(fileName);
                for (String recipient : recipients) email.getToRecipients().add(recipient);
                email.sendAndSaveCopy();
                return true;
           }
           catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return false; }
      }
 }
```

In your code you just have to create the class, then use the sendEmail method to send emails to whomever.

Comment: i will try that, what would i have to put in the serverversion if we have Exchange 2007? And can i use that function without Outlook?

Comment: It supports 2007 directly

Comment: This "function" doesn't have anything to do w/Outlook. It doesn't need to use an email program to get your email... It contacts the exchange server itself and sends emails

Comment: what means directly? what do i have to write instead of Exchange2010_SP2?

Comment: Exchange2007_SP2 is the flag you need. In my case we have Exchange 2012 and I am having to use Exchange2010_SP2, so it doesn't support my exchange server directly

Comment: look at the new answer i posted ^^

Comment: I can't find the class ExchangeService in maven? Which is the library you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaMail code is [not authenticating to your server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#smtpauth), which may be why the server is rejecting the message with that error message.  (Spammers often use open email servers.)

Change your code to call the [Transport.send method that accepts a user name and password](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: like i said, our printers also send emails without any authentification, so it has to work without it, but just in case, i also tried your method, with that method i couldn't even connect to the server

Comment: Did authentication fail?  You might need to set the property `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to `true`.  The printer might be whitelisted at the server based on (e.g.) its IP address.  In your test program, are you sending from and to other addresses on your mail server?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: no authentication did not fail, like in above error mentioned it's the spam content filter that catches the email

Comment: You said it didn't connect.  You're not going to get that error if it doesn't connect.  And just to be clear, the actual content you're sending is the single word "Content", right?  You're definitely not sending anything that looks even close to spam, right?

Comment: no i never said it didn't connect, of course there is other text instead of content, but nothing close to spam... i edited my first post as i found my error

Comment: You said "I couldn't even connect to the server".  I guess that's not what you meant.  Anyway, I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: no i meant when i used your mentioned method when using authentification, then i couldn't connect to server, without authentification i could connect but then the spam error happened

Comment: That's why I asked whether "couldn't connect" meant "authentication failed" or something else.  Just adding authentication shouldn't prevent you from connecting, but it might prevent the connect method from succeeding because authentication failed.